# Do same C++ template usages in different .cpp files duplicate code?

Tags: c++, templates, template-instantiation

Assume you use the same `template_function<T>()` in two other .cpp files (`a_uses_template.cpp` and `b_uses_template.cpp`), which both instanciate the template implicitly.

As I understand it, this should cause code duplication, because `a_uses_template.cpp` and `b_uses_template.cpp` are compiled separately, so `template_function<T>()` gets instanciated twice.
However, if I change the code to use just one explicit instanciation, then the resulting executable file is even bigger, not smaller as expected.

How is this possible?

**main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "a_uses_template.h"
#include "b_uses_template.h"

int main() {
    function_a_uses_template();
    function_b_uses_template();
}
```

**a_uses_template.h**

```
#ifndef A_USES_TEMPLATE_H_
#define A_USES_TEMPLATE_H_

void function_a_uses_template();

#endif /* A_USES_TEMPLATE_H_ */
```

**a_uses_template.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "template_function.h"
#include "a_uses_template.h"

void function_a_uses_template() {
    std::cout << "function_a_uses_template, template_function<int>(): "
            << template_function<int>() << std::endl;
}
```

The following are the two variants of template_function.h /.cpp, first the one with is used together with two implicit instanciations and then the two files which contain one explicit instanciation.

**template_function.h (Variant with two implicit instanciations)**

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_FUNCTION_H_
#define TEMPLATE_FUNCTION_H_

#include <cstddef>

template<typename T> size_t template_function() {
    size_t s = sizeof(T);

    // some code that the compiler won't erase during optimization
    while (s != 1) {
        if ((s & 1) == 0) {
            s /= 2;
        } else {
            s = 3 * s + 1;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

#endif /* TEMPLATE_FUNCTION_H_ */
```

**template_function.h (Variant with one explicit instanciation)**

```
#ifndef TEMPLATE_FUNCTION_H_
#define TEMPLATE_FUNCTION_H_

#include <cstddef>

template<typename T> size_t template_function();

#endif /* TEMPLATE_FUNCTION_H_ */
```

**template_function.cpp (Variant with one explicit instanciation)**

```
#include "template_function.h"

template<typename T> size_t template_function() {
    size_t s = sizeof(T);

    // some code that the compiler won't erase during optimization
    while (s != 1) {
        if ((s & 1) == 0) {
            s /= 2;
        } else {
            s = 3 * s + 1;
        }
    }

    return s;
}

template size_t template_function<int>(); // one explicit instanciation
```

Comment: Generally speaking the linker will eliminate any duplicate template instantiations.

Comment: From standard, to not have UB, your loop ends with `s == 1`.... so compiler might optimize to `return 1;`.

Comment: See for example [C Compilers Disprove Fermat’s Last Theorem](https://blog.regehr.org/archives/140).

Comment: and also '"C Compilers Disprove Fermat’s Last Theorem" with [code](https://godbolt.org/z/3skK9j).

Comment: Thanks for the valuable comments, particularly for pointing out the older question of which mine is a duplicate. I found the answers to my question there.

Comment: @Jarod42 cool code example! I was always a bit unsure if my trick really works. I used this in Java a lot where it worked.